# Kendo Grid UI Html helper enum substitution on row value

Tags: c#, enums, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I've got this example and i want to change a numeric value with a string value using an enum. I've tried a few methods, like .ClientTemplate and .EditorTemplateName. How can i use an enum to format the rows? Here is a grid example:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TelerikAspNetCoreApp2.Models.OrderViewModel>()
            .Name("grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.OrderID).Filterable(false);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Freight).EditorTemplateName("Test"); //This is the value to change
                columns.Bound(p => p.OrderDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
                columns.Bound(p => p.ShipName).Filterable(f => f.UI("shipName"));
                columns.Bound(p => p.ShipCity).Filterable(f => f.UI("shipCity"));
            })
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .Scrollable()
            .Navigatable()
            .Pageable()
            .Scrollable()
            .Filterable()
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(20)
                .Read(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "Grid"))
            )
        ) 
    ....
   @functions {
   public string UseEnum(string x)
   {
       return Enum.Parse(typeof(TelerikAspNetCoreApp2.Enums.Test), x).ToString();
   }
}
```

And this is the example enum

```
public enum Test
{
    zero = 0,
    one = 10,
    two = 20,
    three = 30,
    four = 40,
    five = 50
}

public static List<SelectListItem> EnumToSelectList(Type enumType)
        {
            return Enum
              .GetValues(enumType)
              .Cast<int>()
                  .Select(i => new SelectListItem
                  {
                      Value = i.ToString(),
                      Text = Enum.GetName(enumType, i),
                  }
              )
              .ToList();
        }
        @functions {
    public string UseEnum(string x)
    {
        return Enum.Parse(typeof(TelerikAspNetCoreApp2.Enums.Prova), x).ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a folder inside your View for that Controller and name it as "EditorTemplates" then create a partial view for the **"Test"**. This will be your control for that field and add a **ViewBag.EnumTest** whenever you calling that view with grid because this will be mapped to your EditorTemplate partial view.

Then put this inside the "**Test**" partial view.

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
    .Filter("contains")
    .BindTo(ViewBag.EnumTest)
    .Placeholder("Select Freight")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "Freight", @name = "Freight"})
    .Name("Freight")
)
```

`ViewBag.EnumTest = EnumToSelectList;` so it will have a SelectListItem that will be used in combobox.

Or you can try manually populate the combobox.

```
@{
    List<SelectListItem> EnumTest = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem 
        {
            Value = "0",
            Text = "zero "
        },
        new SelectListItem 
        {
            Value = "10",
            Text = "one"
        },
        new SelectListItem 
        {
            Value = "20",
            Text = "two"
        },
        new SelectListItem 
        {
            Value = "30",
            Text = "three"
        },
        new SelectListItem 
        {
            Value = "40",
            Text = "four"
        },
        new SelectListItem 
        {
            Value = "50",
            Text = "five"
        }
    };
}

@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
    .Filter("contains")
    .BindTo(EnumTest)
    .Placeholder("Select Freight")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "Freight", @name = "Freight"})
    .Name("Freight")
)
```

Comment: I did it, still not working. The method EnumToSelectList is on an external class with the enum. I added the EditorTemplateName("Test") on the bound of the grid column, but it still not working

Comment: try to manually populate `ViewBag.EnumTest` with a list of `SelectListItem` and test it again.